# Can I make flutter code can run python program?

Tags: python, android, ios, flutter, dart

When a python program named 'main.py' runs, it will write some data to number.txt file.
And I'll import that number.txt file in flutter and use data in it.

What I want is make my flutter code can run python program.
I thought about run the python program through cmd, but the function print in flutter doesn't look like proper.
So how can I do that?

Thank you for reading, and I'll wait for your advice!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try checking this plugin. May be it should work for you.

https://pub.dev/packages/starflut

Comment: I didn't try that yet, but it looks it will work. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Note that Starflut claims to be open-source, but it is not: https://github.com/srplab/starcore_for_flutter/issues/27